# shouldn't this loop stop when my character is either '*' or '/'?

Tags: c

Heloo ,I've been looking over the solution for the 1-23 in K&R C programing book ,and i dont totally understand the incomment function , this function should remove all input until it hits the end of a comment ,because of the `||` operator i thought it should stop as soon as it meets an * or / in the comment but the function still works how it should ,can someone explain how it really works?

```
void incomment()
{
    int c,d;

    c = getchar();
    d = getchar();

    while(c!='*' || d !='/')
    {
        c =d;
        d = getchar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Read it out loud: "Enter the loop if `c` is not a star or if `d` is not a slash." Is this what you want?

Comment: I think it's time you learn about [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) on how to negate logic.

Answer (score 2):

> i thought it should stop as soon as it meets an * or / in the comment

No, it will not stop at the first * or first /

Assume `c` is **not** a `*`. Then look at the logical expression:

```
while(c!='*' || d !='/')
      ^^^^^^
       TRUE as we assumed that c is not a *
```

When the first part of the logical expression is TRUE and the operator is `||` the whole expression will be TRUE regardless of the second part of the logical expression.

So from this we have learned: When `c` is **not** equal to `*` the loop will go on.

So now assume that `d` is **not** a `/`.

```
while(c!='*' || d !='/')
                ^^^^^^
                TRUE as we assumed that d is not a /
```

Again, as one part of the logical OR-expression (i.e. the second part) is TRUE, the whole expression will be TRUE and the loop will go on.

Now we only miss the case where `c` is a `*` and `d` is a `/`

```
while(c!='*' || d !='/')
      ^^^^^^    ^^^^^^
       FALSE     FALSE as we assumed that d is a /
         |
         as we assumed that c is a *
```

So in this case the loop will stop because `FALSE || FALSE` results in `FALSE`.

We can write this as as a table:

```
     c     |     d     | Logical expression
-------------------------------------------
   != '*'  | any value |     TRUE
-------------------------------------------
 any value |   != '/'  |     TRUE
-------------------------------------------
   == '*'  |   == '/'  |     FALSE
```

In other words - the loop will stop if and only if `c` has the value `*` **and** `d` has the value `/`

The body of the loop shows us that `c` always gets the value that `d` had in the previous loop:

```
{
    c =d;            // c is assigned the value that d got in the previous loop
    d = getchar();   // d is assigned the next character of the input
}
```

So together `c` and `d` form a 2 character sliding window of the input.

As an example consider reading the test string: "a * is born*/"

```
text | c   | d   | comment
----------------------
 'a' | 'a' |     | initialization
 ' ' | 'a' | ' ' | initialization
 '*' | ' ' | '*' | loop
 ' ' | '*' | ' ' | loop
 'i' | ' ' | 'i' | loop
 's' | 'i' | 's' | loop
 ' ' | 's' | ' ' | loop
 'b' | ' ' | 'b' | loop
 'o' | 'b' | 'o' | loop
 'r' | 'o' | 'r' | loop
 'n' | 'r' | 'n' | loop
 '*' | 'n' | '*' | loop
 '/' | '*' | '/' | loop (last loop because now c is * AND d is /
```

In other words - the loop will only stop when the text string contains the sequence `*/` which is indeed the end-of-comment sequence.

Comment: awesome explaination!

Answer (score 1):

> this function should remove all input until it hits the end of a comment

contrasts

> i thought it should stop as soon as it meets an * or / in the

The latter would require a check afterwards if the comment indeed did end or if it is just a random * or /.

As pointed out it stops if the end of a comment is encountered.
The comment ends if it meets an * **and** / thus `c == '*' && d == '/'`.
On the other hand this means that the loop continues reading until `!(c == '*' && d == '/')` which is equivalent to `c != '*' || d != '/'`.